# Cortar o ultimo caracter de uma string C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, string

Estou criando um exportação do `SQL` para o TXT.

Com isso eu adiciono o separador ";" após construir cada coluna.

Porém no final da ultima coluna está adicionando o ";" também.

Como faço para tirar esse ";" do final da ultima coluna de todas as linhas?

Meu `foreach` de construção das linhas e colunas:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + ";";
        int tamanho_linha = txt.Length;
        txt = Convert.ToString(tamanho_linha - 1);
     }

    txt += "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar o `Substring`:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + ";";
        txt = txt.Substring(0,txt.Length - 1);
    }
    txt += "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Faça isto:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
        txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + ";";
    }
    txt = txt.TrimEnd(";") + "\r\n";
}
```

Documentação do [`TrimEnd()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_TrimEnd_System_Char___).

Na verdade não recomendo fazer isto. Se tem mais do que 4 concatenações de *string*, deve usar [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), para evitar o problema do [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html). O algoritmo como está é quadrático e pode levar muito mais tempo do que o esperado fazendo realocações sem necessidade, acabando também com o coletor de lixo.

```
var txt = new StringBuilder(); //se tiver uma estimativa de tamanho que ela terá, coloque aqui
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
        txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + ";";
    }
    txt = txt.Remove(txt.Length - 1, 1); + "\r\n";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/BuildFromDataRow.cs).

Compare a performance entre ambos.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, deu certo.