# Performance ItextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho, itextsharp

Estou fazendo os relatórios utilizando iTextsharp e o resultado tem sido aceitável, porém ao trabalhar com muitos registros tem se tornado lento. Atualmente faço assim:

Capto os dados do banco (armazenando em um `DataTable`);

Em um `foreach` concateno tudo em um *string*: (ex tosco)

```
foreach (DataRow row in FaturamentoCorpo.Rows)
  stringao += row["ncodigfilia"].ToString()
```

Ao final jogo para o iTextsharp esse "stringão":

```
Paragraph paragrafo = new Paragraph("", new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, FontSize));
paragrafo.Add(stringao);
```

Então esse *loop* concatenando no *string*, quando o `DataTable` tem ai +- 10k registros, resultando em um PDF de 70 a 80 paginas, está meio demorado.

Portanto, queria uma forma melhor de trabalhar isso?

Comment: já tentou: `foreach (DataRow row in FaturamentoCorpo.Rows)
  paragrafo.Add(row["ncodigfilia"].ToString());` ? mesmo que não fique no mesmo formato, apenas para verificar o desempenho ?!

Comment: Seu comentário foi simples, porém pontual, que complementando com a resposta seguinte consegui resolver o problema. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondi sobre o problema em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16063/101) ([outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/101)).

Você não pode fazer porque quanto mais vai concatenando, mais lento vai ficando, e é exponencial, rapidamente fica trágico. Então teria que fazer algo assim:

```
var todasLinhas = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in FaturamentoCorpo.Rows)
    todasLinhas += row["ncodigfilia"].ToString();
var paragrafo = todasLinhas.ToString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Performance.cs)

Idealmente seria bom tentar descobrir pelo menos o tamanho aproximado total que esta *string* terá e instanciar o [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) com esse tamanho. Parece ser possível já que sabe quantas linhas tem e imagina que dê para saber, se não exato, pelo menos aproximado o tamanho de cada linha.

[Mais uma explicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101).

Pesquisando *links* estou começando achar [duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123218/101).

Comment: Obrigado, o comentário anterior resolveu 70% do problema, e nos links q voce passou sobre a performance do tipo string (coisas q eu desconhecia), principalmente o fato da imutabilidade, fiz as duas alterações:

Comment: 1: Concatenar as campos do datatable em um stringbuilder;
2: Enviar cada linha para a variável Paragraf, zerando o stringbuilder;

Ainda nao testei a alteração 1, pq implicará no sistema inteiro, entao preciso de tempo, a alteração 2 usando string comum ficou ótimo.. creio q ficara melhor ainda.