# Melhorar performance em iteração

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho, expressões-lambda

Tenho um método em C# que recebe um `List<string>` e eu devo retornar uma string com a listagem dos membros da `List<string>` ordenados por quantidade de ocorrências e depois por ordem alfabética.

Eu fiz e já funcionou, porém não com a performance esperada.

```
public string getMostOccuredString(IList<string> lista)
{
     var mostOccured = lista
                         .GroupBy(a => a)
                         .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                         .OrderByDescending(c => c.Count)
                         .ThenBy(c => c.Key);

     string retorno = "";

     foreach (var item in mostOccured)
     {
          retorno = retorno + ";" + item.Key;
     }

     return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Usar "for" em vez de "foreach" e StringBuilder em vez de concatenaçao pode ajudar a melhorar a performance.

Comment: embora seja uma diferença minima de performance você poderia trocar esse foreach por um string.join que é relativamente mais elegante e ligeiramente mais performático, exemplo:retorno  =  String.Join(";", mostOccured);

Comment: @LucasMiranda a diferença será brutal, só não faz o mesmo que esse laço. Pode até ser que ele queria mais o `Join()`que esse laço, mas não temos como saber.

Comment: ah sim, eu não vi ali que ele tava pegando o key, bem observado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se o desejo é performance esqueça o LINQ, ele não é rápido, ele deixa escrever de forma mais expressiva, ou bonitinho ou curto como alguns vão dizer, mas ele não é rápido. Ele não é trágico, mas não serve para velocidade, tire isso e faça na mão. Dá uma olhada na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Claro, teste, existem casos que pode não ser bem assim, até porque pode fazer manualmente e ficar pior do que deveria.

Mas o que é pior nesse código é o problema das criações de *strings* sem necessidade. Isso vai enchendo a memória e coloca pressão no coletor de lixo fazendo o sistema entrar em pausas. Isso está explicado em [Por que devo usar a classe StringBuilder ao invés da classe String?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101). Também [Qual o mais rápido na construção de texto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278393/101). [Um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263447/101).

Quem sabe possa usar o [`Join()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) no lugar do laço, a execução não dará o mesmo resultado, mas pode ser que seja até melhor para o que deseja.

Outra questão é ver se não consegue receber uma lista já classificada ou usar uma estrutura de dados que mantenha os dados classificados automaticamente. Não sei se pode fazer isso, mas é algo para se pensar. Muitas vezes a questão da performance não pode ser resolvida pontualmente, precisa pensar no todo. Ou aceitar que a velocidade é ruim, nem tudo pode ser melhorado, se não puder mexer em outros pontos. Só observe os itens anteriores que farão diferença, principalmente o do `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Show @maniero . Obrigado pelas dicas. Realmente a questão das string é bem válida.